# RUNSCRIPT in Linux

Tags: h2

I have h2 installed on Ubuntu. I am trying to figure how to use runscript.

my command:

runscript from ~/dkjs/kjsdgh/lala.sql;

it keeps returning an syntax error 42001.

What am I missing?

Comment: ["The error with code 42000 is thrown when trying to execute an invalid SQL statement."](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/ErrorCode.html#c42001) A syntax error means something wrong in your SQL script, but you haven't told us what the SQL script contains, so we can't help you work out what it is. What is the *exact* error message returned?

Comment: @NeoTom It would be nice if you add the complete error message and stack trace. Just the error code isn't usually enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the file name:

```
runscript from '~/dkjs/kjsdgh/lala.sql';
```

It needs to be single quotes.

Comment: LOL. Yep, that did it. Thanks. It was so simple I can't believe I didn't notice it!